# Tomcat 5.5 FileUpload resource leak

Tags: tomcat, file-upload, struts2

I took a Struts2 FileUpload example from internet.  When uploading file I see that a temporary file is created under the Tomcat's work directoy.

After the returning from my action class I see this in logs:

```
WARNING: Resource Leaking:  Could not remove uploaded file 'C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-5.5.28\work\Catalina\localhost\FileUploadApp\upload__668d4a82_126bffe35f7__7ff9_00000002.tmp'
```

This is weird because usually on the first request Tomcat removes the temporary files, but subsequen request it gives me the above warning message.

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Ok problem was that I has holding a reference to the file through the FileInputStream... silly me.  After I did my cleanup everything worked fine.

The Struts2 interceptor FileUploadInterceptor takes care of closing the file after your Action is executed.

Comment: Glad you fixed it, but you are free (and obligated) to post the above comment as an **answer** and then mark it as accepted :) Otherwise this question wil technically remain unanswered and may be automatically poked up by the Community at times.